# Conducting IPD meta-analysis when studies use different measures

Tags: meta-analysis

I'm interested in conducting an individual patient data (IPD) meta-analysis in which the main outcome of interest is a correlation coefficient between and IV and DV.

The IV is measured slightly differently across studies, and conversion to make them all match is not possible. Clearly, I can still do a two-stage IPD meta-analysis based on correlation coefficients calculated for each study individually. I would also like to conduct a one-stage IPD analysis using linear mixed modeling (with random intercepts and/or slopes by study) for a few reasons: to more flexibly model an important covariate, to assess whether the relationship between IV and DV is linear, and to model aggregation bias (per [Stewart et al. 2012](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3463584/)).

Given the heterogeneity in the IV measures, is this still possible?

### Edit

*Added plot to demonstrate the problem.*

*Would it make sense, in this case, to standardize the variables within-study before conducting IPD meta-analysis? I'm worried that such an approach would lose across-study effects X.*

[image: scatterplot]

Comment: It is unclear what "The IV is measured slightly differently across studies" means (can you give an example, how many categories, etc.). Can you dichotomize your IV? What about conducting a 2-stage analysis and then running a meta-regression to test if different measurements of your IV affect the effect sizes?

Comment: The IV is perceived stress. Most studies used the same validated psychometric scale to measure perceived stress, but they used different methods of creating a single composite score. E.g., some studies use the sum of all the items, some use the mean, and others take a variety of other approaches. I don't have access to the raw responses, so can't create my own consistent composite across studies. Does that help?